Run 3 operation in parallel with 2 operations dependent on result of 1st operation C#
I have below method where, there is a call to a database in AppendExpandOption2DataAsync & AppendExpandOption1DataAsync if the ODataQuery options is passed and valid. However, the data that OData needs is returned by GetMyData and thus the execution of AppendExpandOption2DataAsync & AppendExpandOption1DataAsync shoudl be hold until the GetData is returned, since GetData can also give a 500 or a 404.  But my below approach is increasing latency as I am doing two DB calls. (1 for GetMyData & other for AppendExpandOption2DataAsync or AppendExpandOption1DataAsync). How can I optimize this code for minimal latency without changing its execution output.
public async Task<ResponseType> GetDataAsync(
    RequestType request,
    ODataQueryOptions<ResponseType>? options = null,
    string? version = null
) {
    if (request == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));

    // Verify expand options
    IEnumerable<ExpandedNavigationSelectItem> expandOptions = options?.SelectExpand?.SelectExpandClause.SelectedItems.OfType<ExpandedNavigationSelectItem>();

    (string identifierName, string identifierId) = Utils.GetIdentifier(request);
    DataPreview dataPreview = await dataApiClient.GetMyData(identifierId, identifierName, version);
    ResponseType response = dataPreview.ConvertToResponse();

    List<Task> expandTasks = new List<Task>();
    expandOptions
        ?.ToList()
        .ForEach(item =>
        {
            if (item.PathToNavigationProperty.FirstSegment.Identifier.Equals("ExpandOption1", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                expandTasks.Add(AppendExpandOption1DataAsync(response));
            }
            else if (item.PathToNavigationProperty.FirstSegment.Identifier.Equals("ExpandOption2", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                expandTasks.Add(AppendExpandOption2DataAsync(response));
            }
        });

    // Ensure all expand operations are completed
    await Task.WhenAll(expandTasks); 
    return response;
}


Fundamentally you can't run two operations in parallel if one relies on the output of the other. There are ways if you use something like a BlockingCollection where one writes and the other reads, but that is unlikely to be useful in an OData context.

Is there runtime reflection involved? If so, you would probably (will have to be benchmarked) benefit more from avoiding that.

sorry I dont know what is runtime reflection. can you please elaborate?

As @mjwills said, you can't parallelize anything if function 2 relies on the result of function 1. But depending on the data, how many different values can response have? If you know beforehand at least a range you could compute all these candidates in parallel with function 1 and afterwards pick the pre-computed result. Also if response doesn't vary to much you could use some caching mechanism, but all of these recommondations are highly speculative and can only be answered by you.

Is it expandOptions parsing creating a delay or some code in AppendExpandOptionDataAsync methods, before it actually use response

Nope. ExpandOptions is reading the sent in ODdata query params in the incoming request for the WebAPI. depending on that Odata param value. we are making another API call which is inducing another network latency so checking if we can optimize that part. response is an object of an entity, and depending on what value is rquested in the Odataparams, we pull in additional data form the target API.

Сaching dataPreview or results of  AppendExpandOption1DataAsync can help to get rid of some requests. Because in this code you have to get dataPreview, before make reqest for additional information. Perhaps you can request additional information and dataPreview at the same time, then approve or reject data, depending on dataPreview?
